# SQL Server : a way to present an Excel table into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, vba, excel

I have like 50 different by size, columns and rows Excel files. Roughly about 400 rows and 70 columns each (+-20%). The columns are named differently, the rows are also named differently.

I am looking for a way to move all this fun into SQL Server and to do stuff there. E.g., I would like to download the files from SQL Server to Excel, to make changes (even in the headers of the rows) and to upload them back. With VBA or C#.

My question is about the upload - does anyone knows how to do it? Have you done something similar? Should I do something like this (see code in one article I wrote some time ago - http://www.vitoshacademy.com/mssql-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-with-vba - if this is considered to be spam I will remove it) or there are more advanced way to do it?

Roughly speaking, these are my questions:

1. What should I be careful with?
2. What are the possible mistakes, I should try to avoid?
3. What would you do, if you had a task like this? E.g.:

   3.1. Create a table pro Excel file;
   3.2. Read the headers of the Excel file,
   3.3. Create columns with them and fill the data.

Or something else? I am not interested in great performance or so ever, up to 5 seconds waiting time is quite ok.

I know the question is too broad and etc., but any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use ADO and SQL on this, so on the sql connection something like INSERT INTO X select * from y, where y is the Excel sheet., this is possible from both VBA and C#.  C# would give you the ability to use the SQL Client which would help. http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to move all this fun into SQL Server and to do stuff there. E.g., I would like to download the files from SQL Server to Excel, to make changes (even in the headers of the rows) and to upload them back. With VBA or C#.

Why would you want to "download files" from a database to change the contents and then reupload them? That defeats the whole purpose of a database...

I suggest you work exclusively in the database and edit your data via proper SQL statements or, if you are uncomfortable with that, using a tool like SQL Developer or SQL Server Management Studio.

> What should I be careful with?

Mixing up Excel and a database. They have different purposes and possibilites and should be used accordingly.

> What are the possible mistakes, I should try to avoid?

See above. Check the data in your Excel sheets, it might need escaping because of special/reserved characters if you insert it into the database. Choose matching datatypes for the database columns. Make use of constraints to enforce a certain level of data quality. There's a ton more, if you are totally new to databases this might be a good start (I'm sure there are alot of other tutorials, just make sure to understand the basic concepts): http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/

> Create a table pro Excel file;

Use a for-loop to go through all the files. If they are all in the same folder it should be rather straight forward, if they are distrubuted throughout the system you'll need to either have a configuration sheet with all the filepaths or you need to think if some other logic to identify the relevant files on your PC.

To open a file use the `Workbooks.Open`method in VBA. Assign the workbook to an object so that you can work with it more easily. This way you'll have access to all its properties and data.  Use these to create a `CREATE TABLE [...]`SQL-Statement. This statement will create your table.

Connect to the database and execute said statement via the `ADODB.Connection` object.

The for-loop will do this for all your Excel files, so that there will be a database table for each Excel file.

> Read the headers of the Excel file

This will be part of the step above as you'll most likely need the header information to create your tables (defining the columns, etc.). In case your "header" consists of the first row in a worksheet you can get the contents using the `Worksheet.Cells` or `Worksheet.Range` properties in VBA.

> Create columns with them and fill the data.

Creating the columns will also be part of creating the table. Filling the tables with content could work rather similarly.

Use a for-loop to go over each row and create an `INSERT INTO [...]` SQL-statement for each row, then execute it (or if it's viable for you create an array to store all insert statements and execute them in bulk. I'd prefer this but it's more advanced than simply creating a statement and executing it immediately). Don't forget to commit.

---

If you have any concrete questions don't hesitate to ask. I hope this helps setting up the framework for your project. If you run into trouble while trying to implement certain aspects of the whole thing, there will most likely also be an existing solution somewhere on StackOverflow or Google. I think with VBA I've never ran into anything that has never been done before, there's plenty of resources available to get code snippets for specific problems.

Comment: Well, thanks for the lenghty answer. :) It is an ongoing project, I would definitely ask more question about it and read it more carefully tomorrow. To your question >"Why would you want to "download files" from a database to change the contents and then reupload them? That defeats the whole purpose of a database...<, the point is that the content of the excel are many various formulas, generated through macro, which should be also editable manually. And accessible from multi-sides. And the idea of the project is that there should be a database.

Comment: The database will also be editable from multiple sides, the big advantage will be a proper transaction handling. Don't use Excel to make manual edits, in the future use `UPDATE` SQL-statements or do it through one of the clients that allow you to visualize the database (like Server Management Studio for MSSQL). If the current macro makes changes to your data on a regular basis you have two choices. Implement the macro in T-SQL to make the changes directly in the database (depending on your macro this might be possible) or you'll need another VBA procedure to update existing data.

Comment: To add further to this: If you have to do regular updates based on the data in the Excel files, the answer above will only cover the first step of your project - migrating the current data to the database. For future updates of existing data there would have to be a separate VBA function that generates `UPDATE` statements rather than `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements. In this case you'll also need to make sure to have a unique identifier that will never change in the Excel data, like a product ID or something. This will also act at the primary key of your database tables.

Comment: Well, the updates would be done in the Excel files only. And then the whole data would be migrated back and forth to the server. Thus I would not be using UPDATE, as far as new rows and columns are going to be added by users w/o sql experience.

Comment: Any idea how much memory would such a DB take? Roughly estimates - about 100 tables with 100 columns each? Char(100) type? Without taking into account RAM or processors - just the needed memory. Would 1 GB be enough?

Comment: You can probably calculate an estimate based on the datatypes used. If it's all char(100) (char = fixed length) one column of this type will always take at least 100 bit (there are characters bigger than 1 bit though, so depending on your data it may get bigger than 100 bit). Each row in one of your tables would then take up at least ~ 1,22 Kilobyte if I'm not mistaken (--> 100 columns with 100 bit each per table = 10000 bit per row. 10000 Bit / 8 = 1250 Byte / 1024 = 1,22 Kilobyte. If you know you many rows you are going to insert in total this should give a rough estimate.

Comment: However, SQL Server is no "in memory" database. So it's not going to store all data in memory (RAM) but rather in datafiles (on the HDD) - at least I assume that based on my experience with Oracle (sorry haven't worked with SQL Server really. I guess it will work rather similarly to Oracle though)

Comment: I was thinking of HDD only.